# boost::asio example code segmentation fault in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, boost-asio

I've been trying to run several boost::asio example. They compile and link without a problem, but when they attempt to register async_accept on the io_service they are throwing a segmentation fault. I've attached the code below. It's unmodified from the boost doc.

```
//
// server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2014 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
class session {
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service) {}

  tcp::socket& socket() {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start() {
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                            boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                   size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                               boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
                               boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                               boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
      socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                              boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else {
      delete this;
    }
  }

private:
  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server {
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
    acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                           boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                           boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session,
                     const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
      new_session->start();
      new_session = new session(io_service_);
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                             boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                             boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else {
      delete new_session;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
```

The backtrace:

```
>   gryphon.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::work_started() Line 96    C++     gryphon.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::start_accept_op(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type & impl, bool peer_is_open, boost::asio::detail::socket_holder & new_socket, int family, int type, int protocol, void * output_buffer, unsigned long address_length, boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation * op) Line 480   C++
    gryphon.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_accept<boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,server,session *,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<server *>,boost::_bi::value<session *>,boost::arg<1> > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl, boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & peer, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> * peer_endpoint, boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,server,session *,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<server *>,boost::_bi::value<session *>,boost::arg<1> > > & handler) Line 487 C++
    gryphon.exe!boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_accept<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,server,session *,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<server *>,boost::_bi::value<session *>,boost::arg<1> > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl, boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & peer, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> * peer_endpoint, boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,server,session *,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<server *>,boost::_bi::value<session *>,boost::arg<1> > > && handler, void * __formal) Line 285   C++
    gryphon.exe!boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::async_accept<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,server,session *,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<server *>,boost::_bi::value<session *>,boost::arg<1> > > >(boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & peer, boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,server,session *,boost::system::error_code const &>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<server *>,boost::_bi::value<session *>,boost::arg<1> > > && handler, void * __formal) Line 1020   C++
    gryphon.exe!server::server(boost::asio::io_service & io_service, short port) Line 75    C++
    gryphon.exe!main() Line 32  C++
    [External Code]
```

I had previously gotten this code to work, but have since recompiled 64 bit boost (address-model-64). I think this is the cause of the error, but I don't understand Visual Studio or Boost's build settings well enough to know.

Edit:
Compiler options

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"src" /I"include" /I"C:\boost\boost_1_55_0" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_WIN32_WINDOWS" /D "WPCAP" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\gryphon.pch"
```

Linker options

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gryphon\Debug\gryphon.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gryphon\Debug\gryphon.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "Ws2_32.lib" "Packet.lib" "wpcap.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gryphon\Debug\gryphon.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\gryphon.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\boost\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib" /TLBID:1
```

The boost/stage/lib directory contains the 32-bit precompiled libraries. Would appreciate any insight about the differences between 32 bit/64 bit/multithreaded/static boost libraries and Windows runtime libraries.

Comment: on a quick glance it looks fine. try a complete rebuild. Recheck all projects/libraries share compiler/linker options

Comment: Rebuilding boost without any additional options. If that doesn't work, I'll start a fresh VS project with just that block of code and see if that works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Rebuilt Boost with default options and changed compiler/linker options to the following: (I think removing the SUBSYSTEM /CONSOLE flag was what made the difference)

Compiler:

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"src" /I"include" /I"C:\boost\boost_1_55_0\" /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "WPCAP" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\gryphon.pch"
```

Linker:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gryphon\Debug\gryphon.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gryphon\Debug\gryphon.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "Ws2_32.lib" "Packet.lib" "wpcap.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gryphon\Debug\gryphon.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\gryphon.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\boost\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: The subsystem _really_ should not make any difference here. It's one of those settings that only mean something at link, and _does not_ need to correspond to (shared) libraries used, if only because subsystem isn't a thing on static libraries and isn't gonna be used except on the main module (with the entry point, that is)

Comment: Don't know if that was it or if it was one of the other changes/the boost rebuild. If it was the rebuild, I wish there was some kind of linker error. All I got was the random seg fault (running from CLI or in the VS debugger). Just thought someone else might run into the issue or someone could see some obvious cause of the problem in the flags.

Comment: ABI incompatibilities will lead to [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). No diagnostics are required, and, indeed, rarely are possible. I believe GCC with -flto has introduced some ODR related warnings, though.